# How to remove the last bracket in this case

Tags: java

This is my program

```
package com.util;

public class SplitBy {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String name = "Masala Roasted with peanuts(49)";
        String category_id = "";

        if (!name.contains(",")) {
            if (name.contains("(")) {
                String[] parts = name.split("\\(");
                category_id = parts[1];

                System.out.println(category_id);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

With this the current output is

49)

Please let me know how to get rmove the closing bracket and produce only

49

Comment: Able to right a regex to get value between `()`  ?

Comment: You can simplify `if` statements in only one with `&&` operator.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the `String` on both brackets:

```
String[] parts = name.split("[()]");
```

`[()]` is a regular expression matching both the openning and closing brackets.  As `split()` is splitting the `String` around matches, the closing bracket will not be included in the resulting value.

According to the [`split()` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)),

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

which means that it won't add an empty element at the end of your array.

Comment: This looks more efficient , thank you very much sir .

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
category_id = category_id.substring(0, category_id.length() - 1);
```

Which will remove the last character from your String.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for both parentheses and only print the content in between:

> category_id = name.substring(name.indexOf("(")+1, name.indexOf(")"));

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
package com.util;

public class SplitBy {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = "";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=)(\\d+)");
        String EXAMPLE_TEST = "Masala Roasted with peanuts(49)";
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            s = matcher.group(1);
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```